# How to combine the results of multiple queries into one result

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to combine the results of multiple queries into one result. All queries return two fields, one of them being common, the name field. I want to merge the results using the name field.

Example:

First query result:

```
Value  Name  
-----  ------  
30     John 
40     Nick  
50     Liam
```

Second query result:

```
Value2  Name  
-----  ------  
30     John 
40     Nick  
50     Joe
```

Third query result:

```
Value3  Name  
-----  ------  
  30     John 
  40     Tony  
  50     Jack
```

I want the result to look like this:

```
  Value  Value2 Value3 Name
  .....  ...... .....  ....
   30     30      30    John
   40     40            Nick
   50                   Liam
          50            Joe
                  40    Tony
                  50    Jack
```

Comment: What you have here is a consolidated query. It would be helpful if you have the DDL and DML queries with the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(My)SQL full join with three tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410312/mysql-full-join-with-three-tables)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `union all` and aggregation:

```
select name,
       max(value1) as value1,
       max(value2) as value2,
       max(value3) as value3
from ((select name, value as value1, null as value2, null as value3
       from q1
      ) union all
      (select name, null as value1, value as value2, null as value3
       from q2
      ) union all
      (select name, null as value1, null as value2, value as value3
       from q3
      )
     ) q
group by name;
```

Comment: What do the `q`s do? Are they an arbitrary representation of that self-contained query, or are they defined somewhere else? For instance, if my table was `C7` would I use that for all the `from`s or just the last one?

Comment: @TravisHeeter . . . "First query result", "Second query result", "Third query result".